# Can my internet speed be higher than my HDD write speed?

Tags: hard-drive, internet, hardware, ethernet, lan

i have an old PC with 10/100 lan interface and Hitachi HDD 164GB with IDE interface.
i connected 40Mb internt line to this PC.
when i am trying to watch live video stream from the internet i am having a lot of buffering.
is it possible that my HDD write speed is slower than my internet speed and it cause a buffering?

Comment: I don't known you disk write / read speed but on 100 megabits/s link you can max transfer 12 megabaytes/s.

Answer (score 1):

When watching videos on the internet they will get buffered into your RAM. This is a lot faster than your HDD. I think that either your ISP or the server you are connecting to is causing the lower speed you recognize as it buffers a lot.

Comment: thanks , when my HDD will be the bottelneck? is it possible that it limits the download rate?

Comment: when i am doing speed test from the old PC i am getting 6Mb/s while from new PC i am getting 38.5Mb/s.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the internals of the old computer. E.g., the drivers and/or hardware is not capable to handle the full speed of the internet connection, even if there is a 10/100 ethernet.

Comment: i have 64Mbytes RAM in the board.should it effect the download speed?